# Unable to import package 'pdfrw'

Tags: python, python-import

Did `pip install pdfrw`, uninstalled and reinstalled, restarted my laptop, but still unable to import the specified package as it returns error: `No module named 'pdfrw'`.

https://pypi.org/project/pdfrw/#pdfrw-philosophy

Any advice is appreciated.

Update: Tried installing by cmd, I'm using Jupyter Notebook as IDE :)

Comment: How did you install the package ? From the terminal or an IDE ? Are you using a virtual environment ? How do you import the package ?

Comment: Installed it from cmd, I'm using Jupyter Notebook as IDE :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the Python that you are using with Jupyter Notebook is the same that the one for which you are installing that package. If you have several Python interpreters installed or if you installed Ananconda to use Jupyter, you have to take care of which pip are you invoking from CMD.

If you are using Jupyter from Ananconda, try to install the package using *conda*.

```
conda install pdfrw
```

Another thing that you can do is open a Command Prompt and type:

```
where python
```

you will get the path to the interpreters that you have installed. In my case I get:

```
>>> C:\Windows\system32>where python
C:\Python39\python.exe
C:\Python38\python.exe

>>> C:\Windows\system32>where pip
C:\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe
C:\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe
```

Then you can use a concrete interpreter to call pip, in my case I will do:

```
C:\Python39\python.exe -m pip install pdfrw
```

After the installation finish, invoke the same interpreter you use to call pip:

```
C:\Python39\python.exe
```

Then try to import pdfrw. If you can import it, then the problem is that you are using a different interpreter in Jupyter Notebook.